# Limit where ${x\to 0}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Can someone please help me with solving this limit, I do not even know how to start ...
      $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^{x^2}-1)\cdot\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^3}{5x^5}$$

Comment: You can start by using $\lim_{x\to 0} sin(x)/x=1$.

Comment: Write $x^5=x^2.x^3$ and then use $e^p-1\to p$ and $\sin{p} \to p$ when $p\to 0$

Comment: Yeah, I rewrote it like that too .. but still got stuck

Comment: Are you referring to $\sin^3(x/2)$ or $\sin(x^3/8)$?

Comment: I was referring to $\sin(x/2)^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by the standard limits for $y\to 0$

$$\frac{\sin y}{y}\to 1 \quad \quad \frac{e^y-1}{y}\to 1$$

we obtain

$$\frac{(e^{x^2}-1)\cdot\sin({x/2})^3)}{5x^5}=\frac{(e^{x^2}-1)}{x^2}\cdot \frac{\sin({x/2})^3}{(x/2)^3}\cdot\frac{1}{40}\to1\cdot1\cdot\frac{1}{40}=\frac{1}{40}$$

Comment: Brilliantly done, I never thought of that for the sin ...

Comment: @ZoranMladenovski Thanks! You always need to check for the possibility to apply the standard limit, when you can't then you need to use Taylor's series.

Comment: I haven't learned Taylor's series yet so I don't know how to do it. But hope in a couple of days I will get learn Taylor's series.

Comment: @ZoranMladenovski You need it to solve more difficult limits and others problems in calculus!

Answer (score 2):

$$
\left(e^{x^2}-1\right)\left(\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^3\right)=\left(x^2+o\left(x^2\right)\right)\left(\frac{x^3}{8}+o\left(x^3\right)\right)
$$
Hence

> $$
> \frac{\left(e^{x^2}-1\right)\left(\sin\left(\displaystyle \frac{x}{2}\right)^3\right)}{5x^5} \underset{x \rightarrow 0}{\rightarrow}\frac{1}{40}
> $$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Use the following two limits $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x} = 1$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^{x^2}-1)\cdot\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^3}{5x^5}=\frac 1 {40}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^{x^2}-1)\cdot\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^3}{x^2\frac {x3}{8}}$$
Using the fact that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac {\sin(x)} x=1$
$$\frac 1 {40}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{x^2}-1}{x^2}=\frac 1 {40}\lim_{u\to0}\frac{e^{u}-1}{u}$$
Then apply l'Hospital's rule 
$$\frac 1 {40}\lim_{u\to0}\frac{e^{u}-1}{u}=\frac 1 {40}\lim_{u\to0}{e^{u}}=\frac 1 {40}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^{x^2}-1)\cdot\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^3}{5x^5}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(e^{x^2}-1)}{x^2} \frac {sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^3}{(x/2)^3} \frac {1}{40} = (1)(1)(\frac{1}{40})=\frac {1}{40}$$